# How can i do time series forecasting with missing data

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I am relatively new to time series forecasting, I have worked previously with continuous data at regular intervals successfully, Now I have a data set with missing values, 
for example look at the below sample :

> 2012-01-13  4804
>     2012-01-14  58
>     2012-01-16  6031

Here we see that 15th is missing out, I have many such missing values. Can I apply Holt Winters, Artificial Neural Networks or ARIMA on such data? If not how do I work with such data. Please advise

Comment: one technique is to fill in the blanks with an average, but that doesn't make sense for all types of information.The average can be based on before and after, or just before, or within some window

Comment: @markg thanks for responding, i am working with revenue on a daily basis. So i think it makes sense to fill the gaps with an average value. Do you know any other way ?

Comment: I actually haven't done that much with time series forecasting, the one time I did it I did it in a crude way, I averaged the value on each side of the gap, regardless of the size of the gap... maybe not optimal.... FWIW I was using SQL Server and SSIS

Comment: Filling with the average is a really simple form of data imputation. If you Google data imputation, you'll find a bunch of stuff, which I claim to be no expert in. I've used the `Amelia` package recently to impute data, which uses the [Expectation-Maximization algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm). I think the main benefit of this approach is when you have multiple data columns with interspersed missing data. This may still be an option for your use though.

Comment: thank you @TadDallas for sharing your knowledge, I will definitely look into using Maximization algorithm for data imputation.